# How to map two different variables value in a JSON string to a single class variable?

Tags: java, json, deserialization, gson

I have a JSON String like this -

```
String jsonString1 = "{\"warning\": \"user_id not found\", \"user_id\": some_user_id}";

or

String jsonString2 = "{\"error\": \"user_id for wrong partition\", \"user_id\": some_user_id, \"partition\": some_partition}";
```

I am trying to map the above JSON String with the below class. I am using GSON here -

```
public class ErrorResponseTest {

    private String error;
    private String user_id;
    private String partition;
    private String client_id;

    // getters or setters
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I want to map `warning` and `error` in the above JSON String to `error` variable in my above class. But currently it is mapping only `jsonString2` to error variable..

With the use of below code, I can deserialize `jsonString2` and then it shows `user_id for wrong partition` in error variable. But if I try to deserialize the `jsonString1` then it shows null value in error variable..

```
ErrorResponseTest hello = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString2, ErrorResponseTest.class);
```

Is it possible to map `warning` to error variable as well in my above class? Meaning if I am deserializing the `jsonString1` with the above class, I want to have `user_id not found` in the error variable..

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Do not over complicate. Create two classes one mapping `jsonString1`, and other mapping `jsonString2`. KISS. If you are a DRYer, make a superclass that holds common attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider 3 approaches:

- take a look at the custom naming strategies, http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/json/google-gson/custom-field-names-strategy.html and go crazy trying to map two serialized names to just one class name.
- create two different classes, one for warning and other one for error, and a common parent class with all common fields
- change your class and add a 'errorLevel' field. In thr json change 'error' and 'warning' to something like 'message' and add also the 'error_level' field.

I would prefer the third approach, so you only have one class, and the json error message model is more selfcontained, more readable, for say some.